# Research Funding conditionned to the signing of a debt acknowledgment with amount and debt in blank

Tags: funding, government-institutes

### Question

Are there other countries than Chile where the government requires researchers to sign a debt acknowledgement with date and amount in blank, validated at the notary, to be filled some time after the signing, as a condition for receiving research funding?

(Related: I asked on
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89105/requirement-to-sign-debt-acknowledgement-with-date-and-amount-in-blank-to-be-fi about the practice outside of academia)

### Context

Many years ago (circa 2010), the institution distributing state research funding [ANID](https://www.anid.cl/) (formerly known as [CONICYT](https://www.conicyt.cl/)) via various "Fondecyt" competitions ("Fondecyt Initiation" for young researchers, "[Fondecyt Regular](https://www.anid.cl/proyectos-de-investigacion/fondecyt-regular/)" for other researchers, etc.) was asking researchers to sign a promise that they would return the integrality of the funding received in case they did not achieve the research objectives described in their accepted and selected research proposal.

Some years ago (circa 2015), the same institution replaced such requirement by a more drastic one, requesting researchers who had "won" the competition to sign at a notary's office a debt acknowledgment with both the amount and the date in blank, as a condition to get access to the research funding. Only a few notaries accept to validate such documents, but only because they normally compute their fees for validating such a document based on a percentage of the amount of the debt acknowledgment (which they cannot do when the amount is left blank).

### Motivation

I thought that this would be illegal: signing a document is supposed to mean that one has read the terms of the documents and agrees with them, which is of course does not mean that one will agree with the terms of the documents once it has been modified. I was told that such document was indeed legal in Chile.

As an academic in Chile, I am expected to apply for state research funding, and to sign such debt acknowledgment if awarded such funding (and told "not to worry, as such debt acknowledgment is never enforced by the government"). I find this the most note worthy example of systemic corruption, in the sense that the very meaning of a signed contract is corrupted. I would like to gather arguments in order to try to convince higher instances of the inadequacy of such a policy.

Comment: This seems mostly to be a legal question. It certainly is quite unusual…

Comment: I would say doubly unusual that there is a someone willing to notarize a document with the expectation that some information will be added after they have notarized it. Doesn't it defeat the purpose of the notarization in the first place? You know, unimportant pieces of information like the amount of the debt.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, actually a notarization only validates the document as presented and signed, not future alterations of it. The notary keeps a copy, for example, as does the presenter.

Comment: @Buffy I checked and in many US states for example it seems illegal to notarize such a document.

Comment: `they would return the integrality of the funding received in case they did not achieve the research objectives` sounds pretty crazy to me - it is the whole point of research that the result is not known beforehand. I work in heavily a bureaucratized system, but it is still a responsibility of a grant committee to make sure the proposal is plausible. Contracts with a clause "result provided in full or money back" are more common in the industry, the amounts may be discussed beforehand, but never be backfilled. If an applicant backs off at the last moment, they may get blacklisted.

Comment: @Lodinn My reaction exactly. 

Other researchers' answers range from "nobody forces you  to take the money if you do not accept those conditions" (except that you are expected to "win" some of those projects for promotion and to be allowed to guide students) to "have some trust: the research ministry added such clause because of the ministry of contraloria, but they will never apply it" (but I feel that a contract's role is to AVOID the need for trust!).

Comment: @DavidA.Craven If you could give the list of such states (and some sources) in an answer, that would be (extremely) useful: one could list those as examples of why such process is a BAD idea (at many levels).

Comment: It is hard to prove a negative, even if the list of jurisdictions is finite. Either way, it is nonsensical to request such a document over a clause at the time of signing the contract... I have seen my share of bureaucrats covering their asses, but none were as brazen. Being generous here, it is possible to see grants as zero-interest credits, but one would never take a credit with the sum left blank to being filled by the bank, right? Further, the potential for abuse is vast because the criteria for the successful completion of objectives can and will be gamed, and bribe would skyrocket.